# How do I create a app specific file type for iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How do I create an app specific file type for iOS and then save my app's data into this file which I can attach to emails and then other uses of the app can open this file in the app.

[Mindjet](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mindjet-for-ipad/id440272860?mt=8) for iPad does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this question: [How do I associate file types with an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774343/how-do-i-associate-file-types-with-an-iphone-application).

And read up on UTI: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/understanding_utis/understand_utis_intro/understand_utis_intro.html